# C# How to reduce repeat code?

Tags: c#

I've largely self taught myself C# code, I took a class in college that didnt help much...sure learned how to follow a book. So i've created tools here and there learning by example online. Stackoverflow is my favorite site for that, usually the community is helpful...

Anyway my question is this, im creating a WPF program that does multiple calculations on a number of decimals, the I've been getting by reusing the same code calculation over an over again, it works fine but I know there is a simpler way of doing it with much, much fewer lines. I seem to be missing that knowledge.

here is an example of how i would do things.

```
int int1 = 4;
int int2 = 2;
int int3 = 6;
int int4 = 8;
int calc1 = 0;
int calc2 = 0;
int calc3 = 0;

calc = int1 * int4
calc2 = int1 * int2
calc3 = int3 * int3

if (calc >= calc3)
{
do something;
}
else
{
calc = 33
}

if (calc2 >= calc3)
{
do something;
}
else
{
calc2 = 33
}

if (calc3 >= calc2)
{
do something;
}
else
{
calc3 = 33
}

if (calc3 >= calc)
{
do something;
}
else
{
calc2 = 33
}
```

I hope that is clear enough.. I can repeat the code but I am just unsure how to use C# better, I know it has built in ways of reducing the repeating code, just dont know how to find them.

Any help or examples are appreciated.

Comment: You're writing this chunk of code often? Or you want to reduce this chunk of code?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? The code you've presented doesn't give any context. Please provide more explicit information in the text or use better variable names.

Comment: Just select the repeating code and put it in the appropriate method.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution that pops out to me is to turn it into a method. (I will leave the [access modifier for the function up to you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)...it depends on where you will be reusing this code)

```
int CustomCompare(int leftHandSide, int rightHandSide)
{
int calc;
 if (leftHandSide >= rightHandside)
 {
  do something;
 }
 else
 {
  leftHandSide= 33
 }
return leftHandSide
}
```

You would just pass in your variables:

```
calc = CustomCompare(calc, calc3)
```

You could even change the do something portion to be a custom action that you pass in if you want. Take a look at [Action in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)

```
int CustomCompare(int leftHandSide, int rightHandSide, Action doSomething)
{
int calc;
 if (leftHandSide >= rightHandside)
 {
  doSomething();
 }
 else
 {
  leftHandSide= 33
 }
return leftHandSide
}

...

calc = CustomCompare(calc, calc3, 
    ()=>{do some stuff that will be executed inside the method});
```

[And Func can allow you to return a value from that doSomething action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960)

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter, could you please explain what is wrong with this suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to reuse code among methods of the same class like that is to define a private method for that calculation. This way you'd be able to reference that code by calling a method, rather than by copy-pasting some code. In fact, every time you copy-paste, you know you're missing a method.

If you need to share code among related classes, you can make a protected method in the base class.

Finally, for project-wide "horizontal" reuse you can define a static helper class, and your methods to it as public static. This way every class in your project would be able to reuse your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a private method within your class, then call the method when you need a calculation done. This eliminates rewriting code over and over again.

Example:

```
int int1 = 4;
int calc1 = 0;
Calculation(int1, calc1);

int int2 = 2;
int calc2 = 0;
Calculation(int2, calc2);

//private method
private Calculation(int integer, int calculation)
{
    //calculate
}
```

side note: I prefer to arrange all variables first, then act (function calls, etc.) on it (based on Arrange-Act-Assert associated with unit testing). However, I did it this way to emphasize my point.

Comment: Just as a small note, this is the opposite of eliminating code reuse :)

Comment: @Blindy It allows reuse within the class...so I would not say it is exactly the opposite...but private definitely closes off some doors

Comment: @Blindy I think we both can agree that we don't want to **rewrite** the same code over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Err.... call a function?

```
doCalc(4, 2, 6, 8)

static public void doCalc(int int1, int int2, int int3, int int4)
{
  int calc1 = int1 * int4
  int calc2 = int1 * int2
  int calc3 = int3 * int3

  if (calc >= calc3)
  {
    do something;
  }
  else
  {
    calc = 33
  }

  if (calc2 >= calc3)
  {
    do something;
  }
  else
  {
    calc2 = 33
  }

  if (calc3 >= calc2)
  {
    do something;
  }
  else
  {
    calc3 = 33
  }

  if (calc3 >= calc)
  {
    do something;
  }
  else
  {
    calc2 = 33
  }
}
```

also, mind the indentations. when you start a new scope, add a few spaces to what's inside it.

Comment: While I did not downvote this, notice the repetition of the if...else. That allows for a smaller function than what you wrote

Comment: I do not know who downvoted this (along with all other answers to this question), but this is a reasonable answer. +1 to compensate.

Comment: @JustinPihony If each of the "do somethigs" are the same, then yes, they can be condensed.  If each one is different, then there isn't a whole lot that you can do.

Comment: @Servy True, but it appeared that they are all the same. You can still get rid of the if else since that is pretty much the same if you really wanted, using Action and Func as I suggested.